# Google Colab variable inspector is overwhelmed by 'from sympy import *'

Tags: import, google-colaboratory, sympy

Google Colab has a feature called "variable inspector". The "variable inspector" pane shows the active variables in the Colab notebook. Unfortunately, when the import statement "from sympy import *" is inlcuded in the code file as below, then there are about thirty or forty variables dumped into the variable inspector. This is probs a bug as the purpose of the "variable inspector" is to permit the user to observe only the variables created by the user. Seems to me import statments should not be creating variables that populate the variable inspector? To observe this behavior, 1) start a new Google Colab notebook, 2) type "a = 3" in the code window and run the cell, 3) open the variable inspector pane with Tools>>>Command Pallette>>>variable inspector, 4) observe the single variable "a" in the newly opened inspector pane, 5) add the import statement "from sympy import *", and finally 6) observe all of the new and in my case unwanted variables in the inspector pane. The Colab cell code looks like this:

```
from sympy import *
a = 3
```

Seems to me that these variables loaded into the variable inspector should not be there. I should note that this issue is not a functional deficiency in Google Colab. Google Colab functions correctly. Its simply a matter of too much unimportant (to me) information displayed in the variable inspector pane.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you do `from numpy import *`?  In `ipython`, if I do a `whos` after a `*` import, I get a display many pages long.  I don't think if can distinguish between variables (including functions) import with `*` and ones created individually by the user or their code.

Comment: Yes, hpaulj, same thing happens with "from numpy import *". Around forty new variables appear in the variable inspector pane. In the case of "from sympy import *" know for certain that the new objects appearing in the variable inspector are only a subset of the objects imported because commands that I frquently use (like symbols, expand, factor) do not appear in the variable inspector pane.